# WPF, Prism, Autofac Wizard

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, autofac, wizard

I am tasked with creating a Wizard-Like application that has many Views (UserControls) to load and unload dynamically based on a workflow.  From any point in the work flow, I need to be able to jump to another View.  In concept, the Wizard will know what View to load next based on the actions performed inside the current View... much like a state-machine.

I am looking for some guidance as to how to get started.  This is a WPF desktop application and the current plan is to use Prism and Autofac.  I can be swayed in this plan but I'd need to have some good reasoning behind it.

Specifically, does Autofac follow the concept of a ServiceLocator?  If not, how do I identify and load the next View?

I expect that my MainWindow will contain one ContentControl and the Content property will be bound to an "ActiveState" property that will hold reference to a ModelView that will be mapped to a View.  This ActiveState property will then be changed based on where the workflow sends me.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically, does Autofac follow the concept of a ServiceLocator?

Not sure what you mean, but Autofac supports the CommonServiceLocator. You do not want to use the service locator anti-pattern, though, do you?

> If not, how do I identify and load the next View?

Identifying should be the job of your statemachine. Loading it is accomplished through `IRegionManager.RequestNavigate`. As a side note: you don't need to go view-first, you can also navigate to a view model and have the view as a data template (just in case you're like me and prefer control template + data template over user control).